# Como imprimir uma pagina redirecionada?

Tags: jquery

No meu caso, tem a pagina home, nela tem a opções de entrar no post e de imprimir a pagina do post, sem precisar entrar no post.
Como se entrasse em uma pagina e imprimisse ela.

Comment: Você quer isso em [popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603465/using-jquery-to-open-a-popup-window-and-print) ou num [lightbox](http://sandbox.tse-webdesign.be/lightbox-print/)?

Comment: Gostaria em uma popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a função `print()`do JavaScript não é possível sem alguns truques.

Uma alternativa que você poderia fazer é carregar a página que deseja imprimir usando o método `$.load()` do JQuery, salvar todo o conteúdo da pagina atual em alguma variável, setar o conteúdo da página com o retorno do `$.load()` e utilizar o `print()` para imprimir este novo conteúdo, por fim, retornar o conteúdo da pagina original.

O método `print()` apenas imprimi o que está na tela, não um conteúdo externo. Por isso, é preciso trazer então o conteúdo externo para a tela atual, imprimir, e retornar o conteúdo original.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var original = $("html").html(); //pega todo o conteudo original da pagina.
var pagina;
$(pagina).load("url-da-pagina", function() {
    $("html").html(pagina); //vamos pegar todo o conteudo da nova pagina
    window.print(); //imprimi
    $("html").html(original); //retorna conteudo original
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, qualquer duvida eu volto neste post !!!!